# What evidence is there that Jax Amnell is a descendent of Richard and Kahlan?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth, terry-goodkind

I have been reading the Sword of Truth book series for a long, long time and am actually a huge fan of the central characters. Having said that, I remember the book *[The Law of Nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Law_of_Nines)*, that Mr. Goodkind wrote some time back and there he introduced the woman named "Jax Amnell". Her surname bears resemblance to the mother confessor "Kahlan Amnell". So the question that immediately popped to my mind is: Is she related to Richard Rahl (formerly Richard Cypher) and his wife Kahlan Amnell?

This [wiki stub](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Jax_Amnell) hints at the fact that she is a descendent of Richard Rahl and Kahlan Amnell  and carries the surname "Amnell" as "both Richard and Kahlan had decided that they did not want Rahl as their family name."  I have read all the Sword of Truth books, but never found any reference to such a discussion between Richard and Kahlan. Am I mistaken somewhere? What evidence is there that Jax Amnell is their descendent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only relevant passage I can find is in Stone of Tears. When Kahlan is healing Richard there is the conversation:

> She angrily shook a finger at him. “I know you. You will want to take it off sooner. You always think you know best. Well, you don’t. You will just leave it on like I tell you, Richard Cypher.”
>
> His smile faded a little. “Richard Rahl.”
>
> She stared at him. “I’m sorry,” she whispered. “Richard Rahl.” She forced a smile. “My Richard. Maybe you could change it when we’re married. You could be Richard Amnell. Mates to Confessors sometimes take their wife’s family name.”
>
> He grinned. “I like it. Richard Amnell. Husband to the Mother Confessor. Devoted husband. Loving husband.”